# How do i center an html button?

Tags: html, web

i do not understand html in any way, i made a site using google sites and embedded a button to it using some html button generator i found online. however i do not know how to center it.

this is the mess i currently have:

```
<a href='https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dropbox.com%2Fs%2Fexga4eg4czbgk5e%2Fserver.tar%3Fdl%3D1&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AOvVaw3w-ZKq78fEYypN0HTjEOFp' target='_self'> <input type='button' style='padding-left:17px;padding-top:10px;padding-right:17px;padding-bottom:10px;margin-left:0 auto;margin-top:0 auto;margin-right:0 auto;margin-bottom:0 auto;background-color:#303030;color:#FFFFFF;border-left-width:0px;border-top-width:0px;border-right-width:0px;border-bottom-width:0px;border-color:#d5d5d5;border-radius:100px;cursor:pointer' value='Download Files' onMouseOver=this.style.backgroundColor='#1a1a1a';this.style.color='#ffffff';this.style.borderColor='#d5d5d5' onMouseOut=this.style.backgroundColor='#303030';this.style.color='#FFFFFF';this.style.borderColor='#d5d5d5' /> </a>
```

can somone please help?

For those wondering where the button link goes: it goes to a download page of my minecraft server

Comment: Try to search some tutorial about CSS. Then you will be able to center your html button.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. An anchor element may not contain an input element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work!!
 `<div style="text-align: center"><a href='https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dropbox.com%2Fs%2Fexga4eg4czbgk5e%2Fserver.tar%3Fdl%3D1&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AOvVaw3w-ZKq78fEYypN0HTjEOFp' target='_self'> <input type='button' style='padding-left:17px;padding-top:10px;padding-right:17px;padding-bottom:10px;margin-left:0 auto;margin-top:0 auto;margin-right:0 auto;margin-bottom:0 auto;background-color:#303030;color:#FFFFFF;border-left-width:0px;border-top-width:0px;border-right-width:0px;border-bottom-width:0px;border-color:#d5d5d5;border-radius:100px;cursor:pointer' value='Download Files' onMouseOver=this.style.backgroundColor='#1a1a1a';this.style.color='#ffffff';this.style.borderColor='#d5d5d5' onMouseOut=this.style.backgroundColor='#303030';this.style.color='#FFFFFF';this.style.borderColor='#d5d5d5' /> </a></div>`

Comment: The HTML is invalid. An anchor tag cannot contain an input element.